Open for edit next cell in the column after key press
Can you give me a hint, please? After editing a cell and pressing enter, how can I automatically move to the next cell of the selected column end open it for edit?
I thought I could do it like this, but it doesn't work.
onKeyDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ($event.key === 'Enter' && this.grid.activeCell.colIndex === 9) {
        this.grid.focusCell(this.grid.activeCell.rowIndex + 1, this.grid.activeCell.colIndex);
        this.grid.editCell(this.grid.activeCell.rowIndex+1, this.grid.activeCell, this.grid.activeCell.dataItem);
    }
}  


any console errors when the editCell line executes? have you stepped through that code, and are the focusCell/editCell methods being called?

there are no errors in the console. but it looks like edit is not working.
